# Get multiple inputs and insert in sqlite table

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, dialog

I have a database table with 3 columns (A,B,C). I want to add some rows in the table, for that i am going to take input from user by making a 'textentrydialog' like this https://pastebin.com/0JYm5x6e. But the problem is that i want to add multiple rows in table for the multiple values of 'A' but values of B and C are same (For example)

```
         B = Ram          
         C = Aam      
         A = s,t,k
```

So the values in table should insert in this way:
(s,Ram,Aam)
(t,Ram,Aam)
(k,Ram,Aam)

Can someone please help with this how can i  insert?

Comment: Do you insist on inserting that way? If you allow different ways it gets much easier.

Comment: What do you want to do with the content of the table once you have inserted values? I.e. show a query you want to do on it, or show a desired output of a query which you do not yet know how to code.

Comment: I can insert in other way also. after that i have to execute this query                                                 cursor= self.conn.execute("SELECT C FROM table where B = ?", (number,))

Comment: Sorry, I am no good outside of pure SQLite. Let me know whether the answer helps or where it is not what you need.

Comment: Could you make your own [mcve] by editing the question, taking mine as example, with more relevant sample data? The `.dump`command from SQLite commandline tool is very helpful for this.

Comment: okay let me tell you exactly what i want. I have a database which gives you the plot of molecules. i want to add new molecule into that database. so i am trying to do that only let me show you whole code

Comment: I am making a textentrydialog like this https://pastebin.com/0JYm5x6e

Comment: Here user will input values in the column 'elements' as 6,8,9 and he in other two inputs (name = ram ),  formula = (h202). and these inputs i want to insert into my table as (6, ram, h202) , (8, ram, h202), (9, ram, h202)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal, able to create the output you have shown, with the input you have shown.

Note that I assume you insist on the way to input, which implies using a single table.
If you can accept different input, I recommend to use two tables.
One with (id, A, C) one with (id, B) and then query by using `join using(id)`.

A MCVE for this is at the end of the answer. It contains some additional test cases, which I made up to demonstrate that it does not only give output for given input, trying to guess obvious usecases.

Query:

```
select A, group_concat(B), C 
from toy 
group by A,C;
```

Output:

```
Mar|t,u|Aam
Ram|s,t,k|Aam
Ram|k,s,m|Maa
```

MCVE:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE toy (A varchar(10), B varchar(10), C varchar(10));
INSERT INTO toy VALUES('Ram','s','Aam');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES('Ram','t','Aam');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES('Ram','k','Aam');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES('Mar','t','Aam');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES('Mar','u','Aam');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES('Ram','k','Maa');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES('Ram','s','Maa');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES('Ram','m','Maa');
COMMIT;
```